# How to become a Congress Member

Tags: erepublik

How can I become a `Congress Member` for My eCountry (India)? I want to help in Proposal voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least 100 experience points (**level 12**) any your **party president needs to approve** your nomination for a congress.

Note that elections are held 25th every month.

Answer (score 0):

Stay online on eIndian IRC ( http://www.tinyurl.com/indiairc ) for more than 24 hours a day and do some campaigning(shouts, news adverts/articles) before the elections to get people to notice you as an active citizen(non-noob) and perhaps vote for you. Okay, sarcasm aside, so what I meant was - you can use IRC to prove yourself a worthy candidate...

cheers